# Free leaked box

Tags: rust, unsafe

Is there a way to free the data leaked through `Box::leak`?

I'm interfacing with C code, where one callback (called from C) needs to initialize and return a pointer to a specific data structure, I've used `Box::leak` for this, and later on in another callback I need to free that memory.

Or is there another proper way to allocate and "forget" a rust structure on the heap, and later on free it?

Comment: Yes, `Box::into_raw()` is the proper way to forget it, and `from_raw()` (which you've already discovered) is how you regain it - and free it, if you just drop it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`Box::from_raw` seems to do the trick.

Comment: To be clear, since a leaked box allows you to get a `&'static T` from it, it is your responsibility to make sure the code never accidentally stores one for later use. Doing so would create a reference that is always valid, which points to data which will be freed, causing a potential use-after-free

Comment: In that regard, I wonder if using `Box::into_raw` wouldn't be safer than `Box::leak`.

Comment: Both valid points.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `Box::into_raw/cast/from_raw` to interface with external code, and use `Box::leak` only if you intend to never free that memory. The latter has no casts, no unsafe code, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `core::ptr::drop_in_place`.

The solution is commented line:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d5878aeedf4f3f70824b21e7bf75a1dd)

Note that it’s unsafe.